# How to close two forms and open a new one in a new thread?

Tags: c#

My friend and I are trying to make a simple battleship application with different game modes. When you press continue it opens up a small window that lets you pick either singleplayer or multiplayer. When you pick single player or multiplayer we want the original window to close (Form1) as well as the game mode selection window (Form 3) while then opening the actual game window (Form 2). Currently we can open the game window and close the game mode selection window but we can't close the main window. Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working?
(We just started learning C# about a week ago so forgive any illogical code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Thread th;
        Form1 _owningForm1;

        private void opennewform(object obj)
        {
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }
        private void closeold(Form1 owningForm1)
        {
            if(owningForm1 == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("owningForm1");

                _owningForm1 = owningForm1;
            }
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //singleplayer
            th = new Thread(opennewform);
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
            this.Close();
            this.parent.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //multiplayer
            //this.Hide();
            this.Close();
            //Form2 f = new Form2();
            //f.Show();
            //this.End(c);
            th = new Thread(opennewform);
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();

        }

        private void End(Form1 c)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't put UI code in any non-UI Thread. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I think this is an X/Y problem, sure you can run a new form in a new STA thread but why, i have seen limited need for this over the years. If something is running in your other thread that is freezing your UI you should really address that issue. However this does really depend on your circumstances

Comment: I won't downvote, but just say that stackoverflow is not supposed to be used as a discussion forum for learning the basics.

Comment: @BentTranberg - Why not? Seems to be a perfectly fine question to me.

Comment: And what question is that? "Teach me how to program?"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking homework questions, but I suggest you first google for answers to the specific problems. This particular question is so wide, and has so many problems that it's better to read some learning material first.

Comment: I'd like to clarify this ISN'T for homework. My friend and I are learning to code C# for our own reasons. we're not expecting to learn how to code form this post but just how to fix this one problem we're facing. I did my best to word this post in a way to not promote discussions, but rather answers. As you can clearly see I asked the question "Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working" Where-in I'm hoping for an explanation as to what I did wrong, and how it can be solved for anybody in the future who faced this issue.

Comment: Creating UI on another thread is a very advanced programming technique.  Many significant problems with it, the biggest one is that there are a bunch of controls in the toolbox that you cannot use.  They rely on the SystemEvents class, it cannot generate events in a thread-safe way.  You need to abandon this approach, it is never necessary.

Comment: What approach should I be taking then? I've looked into parents and children but I can't seem to get it to work. How would I use it in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your specific question, there are many reasons why you may not be able to close a particular form. If you close the top level form that's running in the Application loop, your program will end.

You haven't specified which of your forms created which others, so your code does not run for me: Form3 does not have a parent unless you assign it one, which you must have done somewhere you didn't share.

I'll still try to help you make this work:

First of all, get rid of all threading. You don't need it, you are not gaining anything at all from it, and it will take you literally years to get manual threading right. Threading is only going to help you way down the line, when you are maxed out and need to achieve CPU core parallelism. Even then, you will not want to create and manage threads using the old-style approach you are using. You will want to use the Task Parallel Library, which handles most of the complexity for you.

But for now, don't even think about threading.

Next, unless you have some completely abnormal situation and are an expert in C#, you should not use Application.Run() to execute forms other than your TopForm. Leave the default Program.cs code alone -- it runs your TopForm, and the message loop will be exactly how it needs to be.

In the code for your TopForm, create all the other forms you need. Don't make children of children, and don't try to destroy the parent. Your TopForm will be able to hook up events for all the children, and will be able to set properties as needed.

You generally don't need to destroy forms when you are starting out. They don't slow anything down when they are hidden. The parent can hide a child form with `ChildForm1.Visible = false;`

If you want to hide your TopForm, give it methods to hide itself and show itself, and call those methods from event handlers inside the TopForm. Hook those event handlers up to events generated in the child form that wants to request hiding or showing the TopForm.

This way you can have any form you want visible on the screen, and everything else gone. When you need to, you can simply make any form visible again.

Your program flow does not require that you change the message loop. Just handle events (button clicks etc.) to give control to whatever code needs to be running.

If you are trying to create a gameloop, ask another question about that. What you are doing will not achieve that (you won't need it for Battleship, anyway).

Comment: As I mentioned we're brand new to coding. How do we go about organizing parents and children to get this to work properly? Would we make form3 the parent or the child of form1? What's the proper syntax for it and where would we put the code? Apologies for the noob questions.